# Backup Ubuntu 19.10, upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 and restore (if broken)

Tags: backup, 19.10

I'm pretty new in Ubuntu and I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 19.10 system to Ubuntu 20.04 (not the beta, I will do it when the full version is out) and to be safe I would do a backup of the entire system. How can I do it?
I want not only to backup `/home`, but also every file I have in `/opt`, `/bin`, and everywhere else.

Is there any tool to do the full backup? If I will need to restore my backup in the new system, how can I do it?

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:

- Now I'm using deja backup (the default one in Ubuntu). Is that tool
  good to just backup everything (I mean, everything, including
  programs) and then restore it (if needed)?
- If I backup the entire system and then
  I restore it on Ubuntu 20.04, will it break something?
- If I snapshot 
  my entire system and then restore it on Ubuntu 20.04, will it break
  something?
- If I do a bootable USB of my entire system and then boot
  my pc with it, will I have everything (including `/opt` and others)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use and love Clonezilla to make and restore images of system disks.  It's free to download and burn to CD/DVD or make a bootable USB stick.

It's from Taiwan, so the English is a bit lumpy, but correct.

I have used it to migrate several dual-boot systems from spinning disk to SSD and have never has a problem.

https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php